# How to forward received data towards network namespace?

Tags: python, data, network-namespaces, mqtt

My goal is to forward received data to another pc. I have three devices (A, B and C) connected into the same network. A uses pyzmq to publish data in which B is subscribed. Then, B must send this received data to C via network namespace. This is my original code in which I execute in B.

```
import subprocess
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect("tcp://10.1.24.50:4000")
socket.subscribe("")
while True:
    print("message rcv")
    data = socket.recv_string() 
    command = ['sudo', 'ip', 'netns', 'exec', 'ue1', 'ping', '-i', '1', '-c', '1', '-s', str(len(data)), '8.8.8.8'] 
    print(data)
    subprocess.run(command, input=data, text=True)
```

However, it doesn't transmit anything. Any solution?